# I want users to upload an image via dialogflow

Tags: node.js, file-upload, bots, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have created a bot on dialogflow and I want users to upload an image and I do not know how to do it! I'm using fulfilement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is the platform where you create the bot, and eventually you will be integrating it with other platforms from where your users can use the chatbot.

You can for example integrate with Facebook messenger, from which the user can upload an image. And you can use the Event 'FACEBOOK_MEDIA' within a intent which would be triggered whenever a user adds an attachment from Facebook messenger.